# 'peer' command not found hyperledger

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I'm working on this tutorial:

http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

At the section "Create & Join Channel" at the command :

```
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/cacerts/ca.example.com-cert.pem
```

I received this error:

> No command 'peer' found, did you mean:
>       Command 'pee' from package 'moreutils' (universe)
>       Command 'beer' from package 'gerstensaft' (universe)
>       Command 'peel' from package 'ears' (universe)
>       Command 'pear' from package 'php-pear' (main)
>       peer: command not found

Answer (score 5):

Since you are following the guide, I suppose you are using Docker and it seems that you are not connected to the **cli container**, otherwise, it would have known the command "peer" (I might be mistaken).

To connect to the cli container:

> docker exec -it cli bash

If this is not the problem, you can try the command from the bin folder :

> /usr/local/bin

But this folder should be in the **PATH** environment variable, for example:

> PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

Comment: i'm connected to the cli container, because i run this command

Comment: Which Hyperledger Fabric version are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

This error means that your kernel cannot find the peer binaries. So it's important that the path to the peer binaries is included in your path. If you are in the directory where all the files for the hyperledger fabric are residing (ex. fabrics or fabric-samples) run:

```
export PATH=${PWD}/../bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are in the folder ../test-network as I am, try first these two following commands which are in the **Interacting with the network** section:

`export PATH=${PWD}/../bin:$PATH`

`export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/../config/`

Then you will be able set the environmental variables which will allow you to operate the **peer** CLI as Org1 or Org2.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I assumed that your network is up and running.

Please check which docker image you're using to run peer commands.
run `docker ps`
Check the docker images name
chaincode is build and start in chaincode docker image

```
docker exec -it chaincode bash
```

and to interact and run peer commands run cli docker image

```
docker exec -it cli bash
```