# How to upgrage/update chaincode in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am upgrading chaincode by changing the version **in startFabric.sh** file and then running `./startFabric.sh javascript` command. So is this the right way or is there any command like `peer chaincode install -p chaincodedev/chaincode/sacc -n mycc -v 0`

Comment: I think you're referring to Fabcar ? https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/fabcar/startFabric.sh - you need to perform a `peer chaincode upgrade` to upgrade - see https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/commands/peerchaincode.html?highlight=peer%20chaincode%20upgrade#peer-chaincode-upgrade-example for an example

Comment: I tried that and It is saying `Command 'peer' not found`. So I end up here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44655893/peer-command-not-found-hyperledger and here I cannot found **cli container**

Comment: Needs to be run from the CLI container - as shown in https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/fabcar/startFabric.sh#L48 you need the same `docker exec` command equivalent (for your `chaincode upgrade`) to execute it via the CLI container (where the `peer` command can be found)